# C++ pointer collection class for easier communication

Tags: c++, pointers, design-patterns

Is there anything wrong with having a central resource of pointers to act as a communication exchange within a project?

Im currently working on a multi component application in JUCE, learning C++ as I bumble along. Its gotten unwieldy and im looking to clean it up, both to decouple the components from each other and simplify / standardise communication.

The solution that seems most obvious / elegant to me would be to have a pointer manager object holding pointers to all components that need to receive external input, and just have classes reference the manager object, calling the component they need, when they need. Objects would be owned by their parents, and register themselves to the pointer manager in their constructor.

Is there anything wrong with this? Ive not seen any design pattern take this approach, which kind of suggests im about to put a lot of work into doing something stupid.

Does anyone have any downsides or alternatives to consider?

Comment: In any ways I'd highly recommend to use appropriate [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to realize that.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ of course, JUCE has ScopedPointers to handle the lifetime of the object, as stated they will be owned according to the hierarchy, the 'manager' class would consist of raw pointers to the Scopedpointers.

Answer (score 0):

This should be actually a comment but I can't add comments.
What you are trying to do seems like something similar to observer or reactor design patter. 
I've seen such solution in real live systems and it worked well. I'll also seen such address bus architecture in inter process communication solution.
Remember about providing good solution for unregistering from your dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks, the Observer pattern i believe is comparable with the Change Broadcaster/Listener in JUCE. My problem with this is that it seems to be overly convoluted when compared to just asking a central object the address of another object. Same goes for the Mediator pattern, although similar the Mediator doesnt need to do anything other than hold the pointer. It just seems a little too simple which makes me wonder im missing something obvious.

Comment: Well the main problem I can see here is in multi-threading you need some kind of logic to make sure that your pointers will be always valid. But you didn't mention if your application is multi threaded or not...
Another thing is how that central container will be accessed. If you plan singleton or some global object there are very strong arguments against those.

Comment: Multithreading is not something ive had to deal with so far but yes i would expect at least the Audio and UI would be on seperate threads eventually. When you mean 'pointer is valid' do you just mean checking if null? Also are you able to elaborate about the disadvantages about having it as a global object, as that is exactly what i was going to do :)